# for loop taking only the first array value

Tags: javascript, arrays, three.js

I tried to call in the array values like in the code below, However when onclicked i'm able to get the first material in the array successfully but not the others, for some reason it stops looping. Please let me know where i'm going wrong.

```
var White = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
            color:0xf6daa5,
        //  specular: 0x000000,
            roughness: 0.7,
            shininess: 0,
        //  bumpMap: mapHeight,
            bumpScale: 12,
            emissive: null,
            emissiveIntensity : null,
            reflectivity: 0.1
   } );
var sink = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
     color: 0x224466,
     combine: THREE.MixOperation,
     reflectivity: 0.8,
     side: THREE.DoubleSide,
     shininess: 40,
     reflectivity:0

     opacity:null
   } )
var gold = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {
     color: 0x529dc3,                  
     specular: 0x508fbb,            
     shininess: 60,
     emissive:0x070606,
     reflectivity:0.7,
     opacity:0.8,
     shading: THREE.FlatShading,
     combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation
   } )  // have declared these globally

EventsControls.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
    var colors = [White, sink, gold];
    for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        console.log(colors.length);
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                if (child.material.name == "w__") {

                    child.material = colors[i];
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Where are the values in the colors array defined?

Comment: Looks like you either need quotes around the color names. 'White', 'sink', 'gold' (sink?) or to define those color name variables somewhere.

Comment: Array indexes start at 0 and you are starting at 1.

Comment: Have tried using single quotes as well, but no luck and i have defined these variables White, sink and gold globally.

Comment: IMTheNachoMan: i am able to access 1st array object "White" when onclicked, tried using 0 ( ie i=0) , and  tried using i=1 to check for color       " sink" . which is also working fine. problem is its not looping.

Comment: What is `object.traverse`? Is it an asynchronous function? If so then your `i` may not be valid when the function is run...

Comment: Yes, i can access an objects child through object. traverse, But if it could not recognize "i"  i think it should not give out anything at all however i can onclick change one material "White" which is a[0] but wont move to next color.

Answer (score 0):

Array indexes start at 0 and you're starting at 1.

```js
// filler to make the code work
var THREE = {
  "MeshPhongMaterial": function() {},
  "MixOperation": null,
  "DoubleSide": null,
  "FlatShading": null,
  "MultiplyOperation": null
};

var White = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0xf6daa5,
  //  specular: 0x000000,
  roughness: 0.7,
  shininess: 0,
  //  bumpMap: mapHeight,
  bumpScale: 12,
  emissive: null,
  emissiveIntensity: null,
  reflectivity: 0.1
});


var sink = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x224466,
  combine: THREE.MixOperation,
  reflectivity: 0.8,
  side: THREE.DoubleSide,
  shininess: 40,
  reflectivity: 0,
  opacity: null
});

var gold = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
  color: 0x529dc3,
  specular: 0x508fbb,
  shininess: 60,
  emissive: 0x070606,
  reflectivity: 0.7,
  opacity: 0.8,
  shading: THREE.FlatShading,
  combine: THREE.MultiplyOperation
}); // have declared these globally


// commented out parts that aren't relevant to the issue
//EventsControls.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
var colors = [White, sink, gold];
for (var i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
  console.log(i + " = " + colors.length);
  //  object.traverse(function(child) {
  //    if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {
  //
  //      if (child.material.name == "w__") {
  //
  //        child.material = colors[i];
  //      }
  //    }
  //  })
}
//});
```

And is `object` defined anywhere? Otherwise it'll error in the `for` loop.

Comment: yep, i have defined the object and i'm using objects child to change its material. im wondering  if the changes can reflect for one array element why not for other two, i believe i made a mistake while looping it.

Answer (score -1):

Your array consists of several strings, each of which must be placed between double quotes `"`

```
EventsControls.attachEvent('onclick', function() {
    var colors = ["White", "sink", "gold"];
    for (var i = 1; i < colors.length; i++) {
        console.log(colors.length);
        object.traverse(function(child) {
            if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

                if (child.material.name == "w__") {

                    child.material = colors[i];
                }
            }
        })
    }
});
```

See also: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

Comment: Tijmen, i tried with the double quotes, but that onclick object dissapears. after that.However it manages to call the first array object White when i initiate the array without quotes.

Comment: @Tijmen - I don't think you saw that White, sink and gold are actually objects. Putting them in strings will not work.

Comment: i just updated the globally defined variables here in the question, is there any other looping way i can try for this situation. Does a while loop suffice?